# cdi does not inject entitymanager

Tags: java, cdi

cdi don't injects entitymanager, always the nullpointer. Following configuration:

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="tutoroo" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:/tutoroo</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
 </persistence>

public class ProdutorEntityManager implements Serializable {

    private EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("tutoroo");
   //private EntityManager entityManager = factory.createEntityManager();

    @Produces
    @PersistenceContext
    @RequestScoped
    public EntityManager criaEntityManager(){
        return factory.createEntityManager();
    }

    public void dispose(@Disposes EntityManager em) {
        em.close();
    }
}

public class UsuarioDaoImp implements UsuarioDao {

    @Inject
    private EntityManager manager; 

    public void salvar(Usuario usuario) {
        manager.persist(usuario);
    }
}
```

When I debug the `EntityManager UsuarioDaoImp` class, this exception occurs: com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method.

I do not know what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone help?

Server is: jboss-as-7.1.1

Answer (score 4):

*First off, don't create the persistence units yourself in an app server, but let the server inject it for you.*

Here's why, from [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Persistence.html):

> The Persistence class is available in a Java EE container environment as well; however, support for the Java SE bootstrapping APIs is not required in container environments.

Not sure how jbos-as-7 behaves, but it is generally discouraged because of reasons such as loosing JTA support.

*For simplicity, I assume you only have one persistence unit in your application. Please ask and I'll edit if you need examples for an application with multiple persistence units.*

To simply use the entity manager in **any** CDI managed bean:

```
public class CDIBean {

  // the container injects it
  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager em;

  // just use it
  public void someMethod(Entity someEntity) {
    this.em.persist(someEntity);
  }

}
```

**That's all there is to it.**

However, in many examples, a combination of producers / disposers are declared for various reasons. I bet this is where the confusion comes from. Some of the use cases:

- To allow you to use `@Inject EntityManger em;` instead of `@PersistenceContext EntityManager em;`

  ```
  // to make it available for injection using @Inject
  public class CDIProducer {

    // again, the container injects it
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    // this will have the default dependent scope
    @Produces
    public EntityManager em() {
      return em;
    }

    public void dispose(@Disposes EntityManager em) {
      em.close();
    }

  }

  // to use it
  public class CDIBean {

    @Inject
    private EntityManager em;

    // just use it
    public void someMethod(Entity someEntity) {
      this.em.persist(someEntity);
    }

  }
  ```
- or to bind an entity manager to a particular scope.

  ```
  // to make it available for injection using @Inject, and bind it to the @RequestScope
  public class CDIProducer {

    // again, the container injects it
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    // this will be in the request scope
    @Produces
    @RequestScoped
    public EntityManager em() {
      return em;
    }

    public void dispose(@Disposes @RequestScoped EntityManager em) {
      em.close();
    }

  }

  // to use it
  public class CDIBean {

    @Inject
    private EntityManager em;

    // just use it
    public void someMethod(Entity someEntity) {
      this.em.persist(someEntity);
    }

  }
  ```

Finally, the method producers above can be converted to field producers. This is equivalent to the last example:

```
// to make it available for injection using @Inject, and bind it to the @RequestScope
public class CDIProducer {

  @PersistenceContext
  @Produces
  @RequestScoped
  private EntityManager em;

  public void dispose(@Disposes @RequestScoped EntityManager em) {
    em.close();
  }

}
```

Comment: Does your multi-persistence solution requires different qualifiers for each persistence unit?

Answer (score 0):

I think that @RequestScoped is not allowed as parameter injection.